# Creating list of modified sub-words with indexes

Tags: python

I have to make a code for a personal project. I got stuck in dealing with strings that have repeated characters. I need to get all correct indexes of each sub-word originated from a string (of course is a DNA string). I need all the correct indexes of each sub-words combinations (a list of small words build from the original string). I need to build a list of modified words for example, ACnC (take a look in the tables below). However, for sub-words with consecutive indexes like ACG = [0, 1, 2], the word is returned as it is, ACG. I want to work with sub-words of length 2 to 5.

I have this code here to get all combinations of words:

```
def get_kmer_combo(kmer, alphabet, repeats=1):
    """
    > alphabet = "ACGT"
    > kmer = "ACGCAT"
    >get_kmer_combo(kmer, alphabet, repeats=1)
    ['AC', 'AG', 'AC', 'AA', 'AT', 'CG', 'CC', 'CA', 
    'CT', 'GC', 'GA', 'GT', 'CA', 'CT', 'AT']
    """
    return ["".join(c) for c in combinations(kmer, r=repeats)]

> alphabet = "ACGT"
> kmer = "ACGCAT"

>get_kmer_combo(kmer, alphabet, repeats=1)
['AC', 'AG', 'AC', 'AA', 'AT', 'CG', 'CC', 'CA', 'CT', 'GC', 'GA', 'GT', 'CA',
 'CT', 'AT']

>get_kmer_combo("kmer", alphabet, repeats=3)
['ACG', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACT', 'AGC', 'AGA', 'AGT', 'ACA', 'ACT', 'AAT', 'CGC',
 'CGA', 'CGT', 'CCA', 'CCT', 'CAT', 'GCA', 'GCT', 'GAT', 'CAT']
```

I will show you with examples what I need.

1- For three letter sub-words:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
A C G C A T 
A C G
A C - C
A C - - A
A C - - - T
A - G C
A - G - A 
A - G - - T
A - - C A
A - - C - T
A - - - A T
  C G C
  C G - A
  C G - - T
  C - C A
  C - C - T
      C A T
    G C A
    G C - T
    G - A T
      C A T
```

I need to get the indexes for each sub-words that are in the original string and then check the missed indexes (-) and then,I will need to add a letter(s) of the DNA alphabet "ACGT", depending the number of missing indexes.

- When 1 index is missing in the sub-word a combination of four sub-words must be returned, for example, `AC-C = ["ACAC", "ACTC", "ACCC", ACGC"]`.
- when 2 indexes are missing 4^len missing indexes:

  A C - - A = ['ACAAA','ACACA','ACAGA','ACATA','ACCAA','ACCCA','ACCGA','ACCTA','ACGAA','ACGCA',
  'ACGGA','ACGTA','ACTAA','ACTCA', 'ACTGA','ACTTA']

-when three indexes missing 4^len("-") =3, etc...

The same with two letter sub-words:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
A C G C A T 
A C
A - G
A - - C
A - - - A
A - - - - T
  C G
  C - C
  C - - A
  C - - - T
    G C
    G - A
    G - - T
      C A
      C - T
        A T
```

And also with 4 and 5 letter sub-words.

I tried to find the indexes of each combination of words with this function:

```
def get_indices(kmer, sub_words):
    results = []

    for sw in sub_words:
        temp_results = []
        start_idxs = [i for i, c in enumerate(kmer) if c == sw[0]]

        for start in start_idxs:
            temp_idxs = [start]
            temp_start = start

            for char in sw[1:]:
                found = False
                for i in range(temp_start + 1, len(kmer)):
                    if kmer[i] == char:
                        temp_idxs.append(i)
                        temp_start = i
                        found = True
                        break

                if not found:
                    temp_indices = []
                    break

            if temp_idxs and len(temp_idxs) == len(sw):
                temp_results.append(tuple(temp_idxs))

        results.extend(temp_results)

    return results
```

Running it with:

```
kmer = "ACGCAT"
subwords_1 = ['ACG', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACT', 'AGC', 'AGA', 'AGT',
              'ACA', 'ACT', 'AAT', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGT', 'CCA',
              'CCT', 'CAT', 'GCA', 'GCT', 'GAT', 'CAT']
> results_1 = get_indices(kmer, subwords_1)
> for k, i in zip(subwords_1, results_1):
      print(k, i)
ACG (0, 1, 2)
ACC (0, 1, 3)
ACA (0, 1, 4)
ACT (0, 1, 5)
AGC (0, 2, 3)
AGA (0, 2, 4)
AGT (0, 2, 5)
ACA (0, 1, 4)
ACT (0, 1, 5)
AAT (0, 4, 5)
CGC (1, 2, 3)
CGA (1, 2, 4)
CGT (1, 2, 5)
CCA (1, 3, 4)
CCT (1, 3, 5)
CAT (1, 4, 5)
GCA (3, 4, 5)
GCT (2, 3, 4)
GAT (2, 3, 5)
CAT (2, 4, 5)
```

It handle some indices well but many are wrong and I am stuck, because I need the indexes corrects to create all combinations of sub-words with the alphabets letter as explained above. The wrong indexes:

```
ACA (0, 1, 4) -> (0, 3, 4)
ACT (0, 1, 5) -> (0, 3, 5)
GCA (3, 4, 5) -> (2, 3, 4)
GCT (2, 3, 4) -> (2, 3, 5)
GAT (2, 3, 5) -> (2, 4, 5)
CAT (2, 4, 5) -> (3, 4, 5)
```

I tried with two letter sub-words and also get mistakes.

```
AC (0, 1)
AG (0, 2)
AC (0, 1) -> (0, 3)
AA (0, 4)
AT (0, 5)
CG (4, 5) -> (1, 2)
CC (1, 2) -> (1, 3)
CA (1, 3) -> (1, 4)
CT (1, 4) -> (1, 5)
GC (3, 4) -> (2, 3)
GA (1, 5) -> (2, 4)
GT (3, 5) -> (2, 5)
CA (2, 3) -> (3, 4)
CT (2, 4) -> (3, 5)
AT (2, 5) -> (4, 5)
```

I worked all day long and got stuck. If Any of the friends have any idea would be very nice.

I start to work with character distances, but still working.

Comment: Your inner loop stops as soon as it finds a match.  If there are two Cs, you'll never see the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the hard way.  What you're after is the simple statistical combination operator.  Pythons "combinations" functions can create the subword list AND give you the indexes:

```
import itertools

def combos(kmer, n):
    subwords = []
    indexes = []
    for z in itertools.combinations(range(len(kmer)),n):
        indexes.append(z)
        subwords.append( ''.join(kmer[i] for i in z))
    return subwords, indexes

subwords,indexes = combos("ACGCAT",3)

for k, i in zip(subwords, indexes):
    print(k, i)
```

Output:

```
ACG (0, 1, 2)
ACC (0, 1, 3)
ACA (0, 1, 4)
ACT (0, 1, 5)
AGC (0, 2, 3)
AGA (0, 2, 4)
AGT (0, 2, 5)
ACA (0, 3, 4)
ACT (0, 3, 5)
AAT (0, 4, 5)
CGC (1, 2, 3)
CGA (1, 2, 4)
CGT (1, 2, 5)
CCA (1, 3, 4)
CCT (1, 3, 5)
CAT (1, 4, 5)
GCA (2, 3, 4)
GCT (2, 3, 5)
GAT (2, 4, 5)
CAT (3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: ...Hum...I really appreciate your help Tim. Thank you. Thas makes really "easy"...

Answer (score 1):

Two variations of [Tim's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77877118/12671057). One uses combinations of `enumerate` so I don't need a `kmer[i] for i in z`, and the other simply runs `combinations` twice.

```py
from itertools import combinations
```

```
def combos(kmer, n):
    subwords = []
    indexes = []
    for z in combinations(enumerate(kmer),n):
        i, k = zip(*z)
        indexes.append(i)
        subwords.append(''.join(k))
    return subwords, indexes
```

```
def combos(kmer, n):
    subwords = map(''.join, combinations(kmer, n))
    indexes = combinations(range(len(kmer)), n)
    return list(subwords), list(indexes)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jZKxTsMwEIbF6qewutRGpgsLQmKoOvACbIghJRcwie8s2xGQV2HpAg_Fm7BhO3Hb0IVs-e-_z_ef7uPLvodnwt3usw_NxdX32U_jyHAdwAWiznNtLLnAH8lsNVZBE3rGamiyQl60BpziKK8Zj5_vt6_kas9v-P1DVjTW8AZHQkOOD1GeIQVgH0FVgAyUqgAzQvE29g_aivNBHuSRvKqsBayFPlTKFKW0XK5eSKNo5ehxEHqHe5sqqP8FM5UtRDUPUVrkn-Qzk6vwCUQHOCaVqeF4qk77IMpzsZr_J5ZkbD_0HB8HXqw3t5v13UJdRlvachuDpUWnxZ1knXJZpzGI5JTjBUyHUA7iFw)